# No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Add' with these attrs on Android

Tags: android, tensorflow, shared-libraries

I hava look Mobile and Embedded TensorFlow (TensorFlow Dev Summit 2017) video on yotube ,In here [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r9w3V923rk).

In the video , I hava learn some function to reduce tensorflow so file size on Android.

I do here

```
"""Prints a header file to be used with SELECTIVE_REGISTRATION.

Example usage:
print_selective_registration_header \
--graphs=path/to/graph.pb > ops_to_register.h

Then when compiling tensorflow, include ops_to_register.h in the     include
 search path and pass -DSELECTIVE_REGISTRATION  - see
 core/framework/selective_registration.h for more details.
 """
```

the *.pb file is myself , then I get the ops_to_register.h file here

```
  #ifndef OPS_TO_REGISTER
  #define OPS_TO_REGISTER
  constexpr inline bool ShouldRegisterOp(const char op[]) {
      return false
     || (strcmp(op, "Add") == 0)
     || (strcmp(op, "Const") == 0)
     || (strcmp(op, "Conv2D") == 0)
     || (strcmp(op, "Exp") == 0)
     || (strcmp(op, "Identity") == 0)
     || (strcmp(op, "Max") == 0)
     || (strcmp(op, "MaxPool") == 0)
     || (strcmp(op, "NoOp") == 0)
     || (strcmp(op, "Placeholder") == 0)
     || (strcmp(op, "RealDiv") == 0)
     || (strcmp(op, "Relu") == 0)
     || (strcmp(op, "Reshape") == 0)
     || (strcmp(op, "Sub") == 0)
     || (strcmp(op, "Sum") == 0)
     || (strcmp(op, "_Recv") == 0)
     || (strcmp(op, "_Send") == 0)
     ;
    }
  #define SHOULD_REGISTER_OP(op) ShouldRegisterOp(op)

  const char kNecessaryOpKernelClasses[] = ","
"BinaryOp< CPUDevice, functor::add<float>>,"
"ConstantOp,"
"Conv2DOp<CPUDevice, float>,"
 "UnaryOp< CPUDevice, functor::exp<float>>,"
  "IdentityOp,"
 "ReductionOp<CPUDevice, float, Eigen::internal::MaxReducer<float>>,"
"MaxPoolingOp<CPUDevice, float>,"
 "NoOp,"
  "PlaceholderOp,"
 "BinaryOp< CPUDevice, functor::div<float>>,"
  "ReluOp<CPUDevice, float>,"
"ReshapeOp,"
"BinaryOp< CPUDevice, functor::sub<float>>,"
 "ReductionOp<CPUDevice, float, Eigen::internal::SumReducer<float>>,"
 "RecvOp,"
"SendOp,"
 ;
#define SHOULD_REGISTER_OP_KERNEL(clz)               (strstr(kNecessaryOpKernelClasses, "," clz ",") != nullptr)

 #define SHOULD_REGISTER_OP_GRADIENT false
 #endif
```

I put ops_to_register.h in tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework dir , and I define SELECTIVE_REGISTRATION in selective_registration.h.

then I run

```
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so    --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool    --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain    --cpu=armeabi-v7a --verbose_failures
```

In android project ,I use libtensorflow_inference.so run my .pb model,but get the failed info :

```
native: tensorflow_inference_jni.cc:145 Could not create TensorFlow graph: Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Add' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
                                                        <no registered kernels>

                                                         [[Node: add_1 = Add[T=DT_FLOAT](Conv2D, Reshape)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This error beacuse some problem in tesorflow branch have some error ,solve the problem is easy.

`BinaryOp< CPUDevice, functor::div<float>> change to 
BinaryOp<CPUDevice, functor::div<float>>, the change is no space。`